# Word problem about volume

Tags: geometry, packing-problem

Hello I have been trying to solve this word problem but am not sure how to start, I would appreciate some help.

What is the maximum number of bottles, each of diameter $9$cm, that can be packed into a box with a square base measuring $990$ cm by $990$ cm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us assume these bottles are circles with radius $4.5$ for simplicity.

The densest possible packing is hexagonal packing for circles, as shown below:[image: hexagonal packing]

For the first layer, we find that the maximum amount of spheres we can fit on the first layer is $\frac{990}{4.5\cdot2}=110$ circles. Since the second layer is in between the circles, one can only fit $109$ circles. The third layer can fit another $110$ circles and so on.

Then, we can build an equilateral triangle and show that every stack increases the width of the area filled by $4.5\sqrt3$. Given the first layer has a thickness of $9$ cm, the amount of layers that can be fitted is the floor of $((900-9)/4.5\sqrt3)+1$ or $115$ layers. This can be formed into $57\cdot(109+110)+110$ which comes to $$12593$$ circles.

（Picture from Wikipedia article "Circle Packing")

Comment: +1 This is a very nice answer. I hope the OP is pleased - but the question asked only for "some help". Perhaps the picture and the equilateral triangle remark would have been enough of a hint.

Comment: Perhaps, but given that I already posted it, I don't think I can edit it - if I do then OP might go poking in the history and OP may have seen this already.

Comment: No need to edit. But in the future, think a little more about helping the OP learn, which may mean not just providing an answer. And when you post an image from the web, give the source.

Comment: Thanks for the full answer

Comment: Unknown, if you did not know you can accept my answer by clicking the tick below the upvote/downvote interface. This also gives you +2 reputation. @Ethan Bolker I've added where I found the picture.

Comment: Wuick question how did you conclude that every stack increases the width of the area by 4.5sqrt3?

Comment: An equilateral triangle with side length $9$ can be cut into $2$ congurent right triangles. Using $c^2-b^2=a^2$ (A modified Pythagoras Theorem), we find that the other side’s length is $\sqrt{9^2-4.5^2}=4.5\sqrt3$, which is also the height of the equilateral triangle, and thus how much higher the next layer is.